# Running Angular Web App and NodeJS server together on same port?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

I used Yeoman to set up a basic angularjs web app which I build and run using Grunt, and I've made a basic nodejs server with a few endpoints that the angular app uses to fetch data.

However I want to run the angular app and the node server on the same port, is there some way that I serve the angular app from my node server without using `grunt serve` or `grunt serve:dist`? Will I still be able to minify my angular app before serving it from a node server?

**Clarification:**
e.g. if I go to `http://localhost/` it should serve the angular app, however, if I go to `http://localhost/api/xyz` it should serve the node endpoint.

Comment: the angular app should be in the static. you don't need a port

Comment: In that case, how will node recognize the angular defined routes?

Comment: i want explain you with an example. NodeJs have a route `GET /api/users`. AngularJS want call the route and you can do this with :`GET <SERVER_URL>:<SERVER_PORT>/api/users`. I prefer serving the angular app through ngnix (this is real static) not nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows. 
folder Structure

```
/
 /public
  /dist
   index.html
 /models
 /controllers
 server.js
```

server.js is the normal nodejs server starting file. 
`public/dist` folder is the built output form the angular (by `ng build`) 
In server.js file, define all api routers first and after that add * route to send the index.html file

```
// Set our api routes
app.use('/api', api);     // <- define api end point

// Catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
});
```

Here what I do is, if url is something like `http://localhost/api/xyz` then it will hit in the api router. if url is some something other than /api it will send the index.html file to the client.

Note: in the browser you should navigate to something like `http://localhost/` but not to `http://locahlost/api`. By the angular app you should handle(redirect) the miss order router inputs.

I think you got my point. If you want more example contact me, I will give you my code samples.

Comment: Hi @Viran Malaka I need help with the angular 2 and node js routes..
How can I contact you in personal?

Comment: Thanks I will send friend request :))

Answer (score 0):

> However I want to run the angular app and the node server on the same port, is there some way that I serve the angular app from my node server without using `grunt serve` or `grunt serve:dist`?

You'll need to make sure you're [serving your angular app statically](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.static).

> If I go to http://localhost/ it should serve the angular app, however, if I go to http://localhost/api/xyz it should serve the node endpoint

To support both your API and your Angular app on the same express server, you should use [Router Middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router) to separate your Angular app from your API. Look at how the routes are structured in `server.js` and both `/routes/api.js` and `/routes/api/xyz.js` below.

> Will I still be able to minify my angular app before serving it from a node server?

Yes, just place the minified Angular code in `/public/app` and set it to be included in your html.

## Example Layout

The below code is an sample layout of how to serve your Angular app while hosting an API in the same express instance.

#### Project Directory Structure

```
/
  /public 
    /app
    /css
  /views
    index.html
  /routes
    api.js
    /api
      xyz.js
  server.js
```

#### server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var server = express();

// Check to see if ENV Variable PORT  is set, defaults to 1337
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var apiRoutes = require('./routes/api.js');

// Sets up our view engine to load
server.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
server.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
server.set('view engine', 'html');

// This will serve anything with in /public as a static file
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Creates /api section of site
// apiRoutes is an Express.Router() instance and contains
// all /api sub routes (ie. /api/xyz)
server.use('/api', apiRoutes);

// Send views/index.html to the client
// this contains the landing page for the angular app
server.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});

// Listen for connections
server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Listening on ' + port);
});
```

#### /routes/api.js

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var xyzRouter = require('./api/xyz');

router.use('/xyz', xyzRouter);

module.exports = router;
```

#### /routes/api/xyz.js

```
var router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  // handle GET /api/xyz
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: It's not a good thing. Express Support 2500 calls for second. If you put your static app inside express (Nodejs) Every page/js/css is a call (for lot of user you lock the backend). The static app should served by ngnix or something like, not from nodejs

Comment: @gianlucatursi where are you getting 2500 calls a second for express? Metrics are different for every machine. Why can't resources be cached? The static files *could* be served by any server (Apache, IIS, etc.) but you definitely can serve from Express and that is a valid use.

Comment: 2500 it's an example (Sorry i did't specify before).  serving the static files from express it's a valid use but i think that if you have a "Big" app in Angular with a lot of libs/files It is a waste of resources that you can use in other way.